# How to use lightbox in bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, lightbox

I need an internal popup so i'm planning to use bootstrap-Lightbox.
The fact is that i followed this [tutorial](http://www.jasonbutz.info/bootstrap-lightbox/) but it doesn't seems to work.

I only did the basis :

```
            <div id="demoLightbox" class="lightbox hide fade"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class='lightbox-content'>
                <img src="/ressources/images/ciel.jpg">

            </div>
        </div>



        <a data-toggle="lightbox" href="#demoLightbox" class=" span2 thumbnail">

            <img src="/ressources/images/ciel.jpg">
        </a>
```

But nothing pops and i get these errors :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined bootstrap.min.js:6
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'hideWithTransition'
```

Do you have any diea why this is not working? And if you know why can you please give me a little example of what i have to do?
Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 0):

recently I tried something to make images displaying more friendly.
Anyway, in my experience I used this jquery plugin

[Lightbox 2 plugin](https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)
but I had some issues to manage a blank div that constantly appeared when I changed  a select-option, then I found out that Fancybox was the solution and in fact was very easy to deal with.

[Fancybox plugin](https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/)
There are a lot of examples that you can find, so I hope that plugin be a solution.